# Which are the most dangerous and popular botnets that came from IoT devices?

Tags: botnet, iot

The ease of taking control of a **cheap IoT device** makes them the perfect target to craft a botnet to perform DDoS attacks.

I heard about botnets created from a lot of hacked IoT devices used to create DDoS attacks on websites.

How much of this information is true? Is there an existing common threat about IoT botnets nowadays? Which were the most popular IoT botnets and attacks?

Comment: How do you define "popular"?

Comment: I was refering to attacks with big impact on media or on big companies. It can be due the size of the botnet or the relevance of the services attacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Popular IoT botnets and attacks:**

- Linux.Aidra
- Bashlite
- Mirai
- Linux/IRCTelnet
- Linux.Wifatch
- Hajime
- Brickerbot

Reference: [Radware Blog](https://blog.radware.com/uncategorized/2018/03/history-of-iot-botnets/)

Comment: From the source, I'm not sure the last ones can be labelled as "popular", just that they exist.

Answer (score 0):

The truth is that IoT is a new trend, a new surface with a lot of possibilities, and one of the most popular IoT botnets is [Mirai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirai_(malware)), here is a brief description of it:

> Mirai (Japanese for "the future", 未来) is a malware that turns
>   networked devices running Linux into remotely controlled "bots" that
>   can be used as part of a botnet in large-scale network attacks. It
>   primarily targets online consumer devices such as IP cameras and home
>   routers. The Mirai botnet was first found in August 2016 by
>   MalwareMustDie, a whitehat malware research group, and has been
>   used in some of the largest and most disruptive distributed denial of
>   service (DDoS) attacks, including an attack on 20 September 2016 on
>   computer security journalist Brian Krebs's web site, an attack on
>   French web host OVH, and the October 2016 Dyn cyberattack.
>   According to a leaked chat log between Anna-senpai and Robert Coelho,
>   Mirai was named after the 2011 TV anime series Mirai Nikki.

If you want to check the source code, [here](https://github.com/jgamblin/Mirai-Source-Code) it is. Also you can check [this report](https://pages.arbornetworks.com/rs/082-KNA-087/images/FOR_IoT_DDoS_Attacks.pdf) from Arbor Networks about IoT DDoS Attacks for further information.

Hope it helps.